# Why is calculus necessary to solve this optimization problem?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Is it at all possible to solve this problem without using calculus?? I get how to solve this problem using calculus and optimization, but is there no way to use algebra or something else to solve this problem? Like a system of equations and using the sqrt of 180?

A poster is to have an area of 180 in^2 with 1-inch margins at the bottom and sides,
and a 2-inch margin at the top. What dimensions of the poster will give the largest
printed area?

Comment: It is possible to solve this problem without calculus. How have you set up the problem?

Comment: @Chance Welcome to Math SE. See [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: I think the necessity of using something in order to SOLVE something is not as meaningful as the necessity of using something in order to PROVE something, which is what is properly defined and discussed in mathematics. The first kind of question usually has a negative answer: it is usually not necessary. Then the question is how not to use something?

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** For any nonnegative numbers $a$, $b$,
$$
\frac{a + b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab},
$$
with equality if and only if $a = b$.

**Proof.** Note that
$$
\frac{a + b}{2} - \sqrt{ab} = \frac{(\sqrt{a})^2 - 2\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b} + (\sqrt{b})^2}{2} = \frac{(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2}{2} \geq 0.
$$

---

**Disclaimer.** I am not good at English. I hope that I have understood the word problem. However, I believe that the optimization method that I use is correct.

---

Suppose that the length and width of the poster is $x$ and $y$, respectively. The printed area is
$$
(x - 1 - 1) (y - 2 - 1) = (x-2)(y-3) = (xy + 6) - (3x + 2y) = 186 - (3x + 2y).
$$
Note that
$$
3x + 2y \geq 2 \sqrt{3x \cdot 2y} = 12\sqrt{30},
$$
with equality if and only if $3x = 2y$.
Hence
$$
(x - 1 - 1) (y - 2 - 1) \leq 186 - 12\sqrt{30},
$$
with equality if and only if $x = 2\sqrt{30}$ and $y = 3\sqrt{30}$.

Comment: FYI, your lemma is commonly known as the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you for informing me of the name of the lemma.

Comment: Without appealing to this lemma, you can also use simple geometry of parabolas, and complete the square to find the vertex. This is how it is taught in precalculus courses.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you sm for the solution !!